# Wordpress: Gantry 5 Framework & Advanced Custom Fields: Run PHP Code

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF to let the User insert a URL. Now I want to run the standard PHP Code:

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>
```

Is there a special how to do this in Gantry? The "Custom HTML Particle" does not support PHP.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is late but will could help someone else.

There is simple way, if you want to write some php in Gantry. just download a plugin like  **PHP Text Widget** . This particle extend standart text widgeT. In your layout you will use The particle Widget and pick up the standart Text widget.

Sorry for my bad english